# Text in table cells is not correctly aligned horizontally

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment, cell-format

I copied a table from one Microsoft word file to another, but it has copied an issue appeared in aligning the cells' text. I chose center alignment, but the text is aligned in the middle but with some padding to the right!
As in the image:

[image]

I checked the text in the cells to ensure that there is no white spaces.

Comment: Check for paragraph left indent

Comment: Thanx @DavidPostill

Comment: Also, check to see if there's any additional spaces before or after the text.  That happens sometimes when importing or copy/pasting into Excel.

Comment: @Damian T. Check the last line in my post